# Mixing manual and automatic partition assignments in different Kafka consumer groups

Tags: java, apache-kafka

According to the [Kafka consumer documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/30/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html) there are two ways for a Kafka consumer to register itself with Kafka: Either it subscribes to a topic or it assigns itself to partitions. In the first case, Kafka will balance the partitions of this topic between multiple instances of consumer with the same group.id, in the second case the consumers themselves are responsible for this.

Obviously it makes little sense to mix these two approaches within a consumer group. And the [Kafka documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/30/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html) explicitly states that this isn't not possible:

> Note that it isn't possible to mix manual partition assignment (i.e.
> using assign) with dynamic partition assignment through topic
> subscription (i.e. using subscribe).

However it does not clearly state the scope within which that is not possible. Therefore my question:

Is it possible to have on the same topic a consumer with manual partition assignment and other consumers with a different group.id with dynamic partition assignment
through topic subscription?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as there is a different group ID, then yes, there is no limitation to using `assign` or `subscribe` on the same topic